# How to disable only updatedAt field in sequelize?

Tags: node.js, database, sequelize.js

I need to disable field updatedAt. I now, that there is a solution to put

```
timestamps: false,
```

into model, but it also will disable field createdAt, which necessary.

Comment: set a default value for `createdAt` and set `timestamps: false`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set `timestamps: false` and add the createdAt field in your model.

```
...
createdAt: {
      type: DataTypes.DATE,
      defaultValue: sequelize.literal('NOW()')
    }
...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define this when initializing the sequelize object.

```
const sequelize = new Sequelize('test', 'postgres', 'postgres', {
 host: '127.0.0.1',
 dialect: 'postgres',
define: {
    timestamps: false
   },
});
```